# How to use logical statements in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables one tables content some value like ID, KMS year, From Date, To date where value in each column is like this

`1, 2018-2019, 01-11-2018, 31-10-2019`

And other table I am getting a transaction date value. Now according to transaction date KMS year need to define if transaction date range within `1-11-2018 to 31-10-2019` then KMS year will be `2018-2019`.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I create a new table and from that I fetched the data in this way.

```
(select KMS_Year from [dbo].[Tbl_Kms_Year] where a.Inv_Date between FromDate and ToDate) as KMS_Year
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'IF' statement for your query. example below,

If 'TransactionDate' between '1-11-2018' and '31-10-2019'
begin
select * from 'any Table Name'
end

Answer (score 0):

### You can have two simple ways:

- Using IF/ELSE

```sql
IF (TransactionDate BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo)
SELECT...
```

---

- Using AND in WHERE statement

```sql
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TransactionDate BETWEEN DateFrom AND DateTo
```

I prefer `Using AND in WHERE statement` but you can use any of these as per your scenario.